# Return null values

Tags: java

I want to show for display a few values.

I want to display a student's inserted notes on the screen. First of all, I insert the number of notes, then I write the notes (int), and finally, I return the values of the notes. The problem is that when returning note values: returns null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfBLp.png)

**Class Notas:**

```
package notas;

public class Notas {
    private int identificador;
    private String texto;

    public Notas(int identificador, String texto) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public int getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }

    public void setIdentificador(int identificador) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nota{" +
                "identificador=" + identificador +
                ", texto='" + texto + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Class Blocnotas:**

```
package notas;
import java.util.*;

public class BlocNotas extends Notas{
    public int tamano;
    public String[] notas;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    public BlocNotas(int identificador, String texto) {
        super(identificador, texto);
    }
    
    public int getTamano() {
        return tamano;
    }

    public void setTamano(int tamano) {
        this.tamano = tamano;
    }

    public String[] getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(String[] notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    public void cantidadNotas(){
        System.out.print("¿Cuántas notas va a introducir? ");
        tamano = entrada.nextInt();
    }

    public void introducirNotas(){
        String[] notas = new String[getTamano()];
        int i;
        System.out.println("Introduzca sus "+tamano+" notas..");
        for(i=0; i<tamano; i++){
            System.out.print("Inserte su nota n"+(i+1)+": ");
            notas[i] = entrada.next();
        }
    }

    public void listarNotas(){
        String[] notas = new String[getTamano()];
        System.out.println("Aquí puede ver las notas del bloc de notas:");
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<tamano; i++){
            System.out.print(notas[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

A example (**Main.java**):

```
package notas;
import notas.BlocNotas;
import notas.Notas;

public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlocNotas bn = new BlocNotas(1, "Maths");
        bn.cantidadNotas();
        bn.introducirNotas();
        bn.listarNotas();
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re assigning to a local variable rather than your field.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In the method listasNotas()?

Comment: Both places you use the array you declare a local variable that shadows the field.

Comment: So what would be a possible arrangement/fix?

Comment: Don’t declare local variables that shadow the field you’re trying to write to/read from.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Im losing, sorry.

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created **String[] notas** separately as a local array inside the **introducirNotas()** and **listarNotas()** method.
The values included in that **String[] notas** local array do not replace the global **String[] notas** array.

Therefore, when inserting values, the array with those values should be assigned to the global **String[] notas** array.

> setNotas(notas);[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxDwc.png)

```
public void introducirNotas(){
    String[] notas = new String[getTamano()];
    int i;
    System.out.println("Introduzca sus "+tamano+" notas..");
    for(i=0; i<tamano; i++){
        System.out.print("Inserte su nota n"+(i+1)+": ");
        notas[i] = entrada.next();
    }
    setNotas(notas);
}
```

When the values are retrieving, the global **String[] notas** array with those values must be assigned to the local array.

> String[] notas = getNotas();

```
public void listarNotas(){
    String[] notas = getNotas();
    System.out.println("Aquí puede ver las notas del bloc de notas:");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<tamano; i++){
        System.out.print(notas[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now i undestand, I needed an array, as a Strings variable, to save it out of the method. String[] notas = getNotas(); Thanks @Madushan